# HDMI Second Monitor

Tags: monitor

I have Ubuntu 16.10. The monitor is HP Pavilion 32 32-inch display.
When I plug in the HDMI plug screen goes black. If I pull plug out it remains
black. I need to power off then power back on.
Don't have a clue. I'll search some more on web...

Comment: Some video cards don't like it when the plug is inserted or removed when the computer is powered on. Does your monitor work when you plug in while the system is down and then powered on?

Comment: No. Still blackness...

Comment: Have you tried another HDMI cable?

Comment: Yep. No luck...

Comment: Check your system whether, despite the monitor being blank, it is detected by the system. Graphical: `Settings-> Display`, command line: `xrandr`. For example, in my system `xrandr`shows monitors on VGA-1 and HDMI-3. Force VGA-1 off: `xrandr --output VGA-1 --off`. Turn it on and position it left of the main monitor: `xrandr --output VGA-1 --left-of HDMI-3`. Find examples of `xrandr` in Aks Ubuntu. If this doesn't help you resolving your issue, then perhaps your graphics card has an hardware problem and  you should consider having it checked and repaired. Otherwise I am out of ideas. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I'll need to explore the command xrandr, right now is says:

Comment: Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvidia-375 seems to have solved the problem. Don't know why, but I'm not complaining